# Where can I find a list of all standard theme brushes when writing XAML?

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui-3, winui

Where can I find a **visual** list of all the standard theme brushes available to me in UWP/WinUI3 XAML?

For example, the [High Contrast themes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/accessibility/high-contrast-themes) documentation includes a visual list of all the colors, augmented with descriptions of their intended use. Is there anything like this for *non*-high contrast colors?

[image: high contrast themes page]

Most helpful resources I've found:

- [XAML Theme Resources#The XAML color ramp and theme-dependent brushes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-theme-resources#the-xaml-color-ramp-and-theme-dependent-brushes) - points to the full list of colors in WinUI:
- [WinUI's `Common_themeresources_any.xaml`](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/CommonStyles/Common_themeresources_any.xaml) - a daunting list of all colors, and it's hard to know which high-level brush to use without visual examples.
- [High Contrast themes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/accessibility/high-contrast-themes) - see above.
- [Fluent XAML Theme Editor](https://github.com/microsoft/fluent-xaml-theme-editor) app - simple app for creating custom themes, but hard to use as a reference.

Other documentation I've found:

- [Color in Windows apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/color) - mentions the accent color ramp.
- [XAML styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-styles) - general documentation about XAML styling.
- [Windows.UI.Colors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.colors?view=winrt-22621) - many friendly colors ("red", "blue", e.g.), but not system colors.

So: **is there a good visual reference of system brushes for UWP/WinUI3 developers?**

---

Another example of what I'm looking for, the accent color palette from [Color in Windows Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/color):

[image: Accent color palette]

Comment: I guess there isn't. Great list for reference by the way.

Comment: The upcoming version [WinUI 3 Gallery](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/671870147354427422/1084140289070993448/WinUIGallery.gif) might have what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew KeepCoding's comments are right---the new [WinUI3 Gallery](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/9P3JFPWWDZRC?hl=en-us&gl=US) ([GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery)), released *this morning* has a new **Colors** section with exactly this documentation:

[image: Colors Fill section in WinUI3 Gallery]

[image: Colors Signal section in WinUI3 Gallery]

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to the styles in your generic.xaml file, on your computer. Just search for this file in C:. This file may give more information than other sources.